# Raspberry Pi Custom SD Card Image

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a project uses Qt GUI which works on raspberry-pi2; however I don't want users to interact with the operating system. I just want that the only application appears on the screen (from boot to shutdown) to be is my application. Actually the [retropie](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/) project has done what I actually want. So I want to prepare an minimal SD Card image like that. Is there any tool or way to do that?

Comment: This is not programming related. I suggest you try asking at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use openembedded http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page for this.
Creat file that describe packages for your image, at your case base system + qt,
plus create description of package of your program, that include .service file for run you program at start with systemd. The command `MACHINE=raspberry-something bitbake your-image`

Comment: I also saw https://openwrt.org if it is an alternative to open embedded. If so, in my opinion openwrt is more documented. But i will try both.

Comment: I don't think this is the  same. openwrt is distributive, while openembbed is framework to create distributives.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the init scripts to run your application as soon as possible and make it handle all user inputs (keyboard and mouse) properly, without giving any way to the user to close it.